# How can I fill data frames with NAN with same values of previous data frames from the same list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a list of data frames `A` most of them are NAN data frames some of them are not, I would like to fill all NAN data frames with same values of the previous data frames (that do not contain NAN) in the list.
Here's a small example:

```
A=[]

data = {'set_of_numbers': [1,2,3,4,4,5,9]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['set_of_numbers'])
data2 = {'set_of_numbers': [0,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2,columns=['set_of_numbers'])
data3 = {'set_of_numbers': [3,3,3,8,4,5,8]}
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data3,columns=['set_of_numbers'])
data4 = {'set_of_numbers': [0,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]}
df4 = pd.DataFrame(data4,columns=['set_of_numbers'])

A.append(df1)
A.append(df2)
A.append(df3)
A.append(df4)  
A
```

I would like to have the output shown in the second picture, where all nan dataframes are filled with values of previous data frames

[image]

[image: I would like to have this output:]

Comment: by fill do you mean copy entire dataframe into new one?

Comment: @Ehsan, yeah that could work also.. In reality I have a list containing around 100 dataframes, 80 of them are full of nan. So I basically would like to loop over the list and in the end I can have a list  where the nan dataframes are replaced by copies of the previous data frames (that do not contain nan values) in the list. does that make sence? Do you think it's doable?

Comment: Do you wish to convert nans to same dtype of previously full dataframe? (nan data frames are float)

Comment: @Ehsan, so for example, df2 df3... df10 would be copies of df1(which does not contain nan). df12... df20 would be copies of df11(which does not contain nan)

Comment: @Ehsan, yes same dtype

Comment: Please check out the posted solution to see if it works. Thank you

Comment: @Ehsan, thank you for your answer. It did not work, the nan data frames are still there.

Comment: @Ehsan, I think it's because in reality the filled data frames are seperated with more than one nan data frame. So in my real data: I have df (filled) then df2......df10 (nan). df11(filled) then df12..df15 (nan).

Comment: It should work. You probably need to explain your problem in a better way. The post covers multiple nan data frames in a row.

Comment: Hi @Ehsan, yeah sorry it worked :). I have an additional questions, what if the first row in the nan data frames was equal to 0 not NAN.  How can I replace the 0 with the value of the first row from previous filled data frames ? I edited the question

Comment: depends. Can your filled data frames have any nan values? or are they fully filled?

Comment: @Ehsan, they are fully filled

Comment: Please find my edit on the post to resolve that case. Please consider accepting/upvoting if it solves your issue. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks @Ehsan, I appreciate your help :) it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

```
for i, df in enumerate(A):
  df[df.isnull()] = A[i-1]
```

or if you wish to change the dtype of previously non-nan df:

```
for i, df in enumerate(A):
  if df.isnull().all().all():
    A[i] = A[i-1].copy()
```

per OP's **EDIT** on question:

```
for i, df in enumerate(A):
  if df.isnull().any().any():
    A[i] = A[i-1].copy()
```

output:

```
[   set_of_numbers
0               1
1               2
2               3
3               4
4               4
5               5
6               9,    set_of_numbers
0               1
1               2
2               3
3               4
4               4
5               5
6               9,    set_of_numbers
0               3
1               3
2               3
3               8
4               4
5               5
6               8,    set_of_numbers
0               3
1               3
2               3
3               8
4               4
5               5
6               8]
```